# aiohttp 2.2 compatible library for async OAuth requests?

Tags: python, oauth, aiohttp

So, I need to make some requests to the Github API, which requires OAuth2 authentication for a much more relaxed rate limit - there is a library called aioauth-client which can provide this, but it is based on a very old version of aiohttp (1.0.5), and I am using aiohttp 2.2, so there are multiple errors when trying to make requests - is there another async library for Github OAuth 2 requests that is fully compatible with aiohttp 2.2?

Comment: why not use python-requests ? it will be far more easy for you

Comment: unlikely and that questions is not a good SO question...

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/CanopyTax/aiohttp-oauth